# Parse string ignoring whitespaces in relative position - sscanf

Tags: c, string, formatting

I have a string at about this pattern `%s=%s`. Possible inputs could be `h = 4` or `h= 4` or `h =4` and so on (whitespace location, if existing, doesn't interrupt input. Obviously the 'h' and the '4' are just an example, my intention is to this with any string). I don't mind not removing the space when formatting the input string (input e.g `h = 4` resulting in `"h "` and `" 4"` as I could trim them eventually myself, although it will be obviously better if such option is available). `%s=%s` as a format string would only receive one of the strings (the first one) if a space was to be entered.

What format string should I use to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take input using [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) which will also take spaces if present in a character array .

Then format the string and store in different vairables using [`sscanf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) . In this way it wont matter how user enter the string , you can format and store according to your desire.